# Modx Evo, evoBabel проблема с url главной страницы

Tags: modx, evo

Всем привет, этот вопрос к тем, кто работал с плагином evoBabel для создания мультиязычности на modx evo.

> вот структура сайта:

[image: структура сайта]

`English` и `Русский` - это страницы контейнеры с пустым шаблоном, псевдонимы соответственно `en` и `ru`

`Home` и `Главная` - это главные страницы своей языковой версии (они связаны через tv поле `relation`), псевдонимы у обоих `index`

Проблема в том, что, русская версия открывается как `site.com/ru/index`, а нужно чтоб открывалась как `site.com/ru`.

Сделать каталог `Русский` главной страницей и настроить связи не вариант, т.к. ломается переключение языка на главной (в сессии не меняется язык), может кто знает как можно это реализовать иначе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решено, сделал при помощи такой структуры

```
English (псевдоним en)
    Home (псевдоним en)
        Остальные страницы
Русский (псевдоним ru)
    Главная (псевдоним ru)
        Остальные страницы
```

страницы English, Home, Русский не участвуют в url

Главная участвует в url

Answer (score 0):

Иногда требуется чтобы была замена /en/index.html на просто /en/
Перед дружественными URL в .htaccess пишем

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^en/index.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^en/$ /en/index.html [L]

# For Friendly URLs
```

для других языков соответственно меняем алиас языка